# How to calculate multiple user input values with fixed price?

Tags: php, laravel, calculator

**Background info:**

I'm currently working on a calculator and need to calculate current income based on amount of buildings the user has purchased

**Example:**

User inputs he has 3 houses and 4 mansions.
Each house gives $500 income and each mansion gives $1,000 income.

The submit button would return the user has $5,500 income

---

I've tried:

```
$a=$_GET['house'];
$b=$_GET['houseprice'];
echo "Sum : ",$a+'975';
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel? You should use ‘Request’, not access the ‘$_GET’ vats directly.

Comment: Yes I am using laravel, but pretty new to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$a= floatval($_GET['house']); // 1000.00
$b= floatval($_GET['houseprice']); // 1000.00
echo "Sum : ".  $a + 975; // 1975.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly you can just get all the inputs and do the math:

```
$houses = $request->input('houses');
$housePricing = 500;
//$housePricing = $request->input('house_pricing');

$mansions = $request->input('mansions');
$mansionPricing = 1000;
//$mansionPricing = $request->input('mansion_pricing');

$total = ($houses * $housePricing) + ($mansions * $mansionPricing);
```